# Taylor series and calculating a sum with its help

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

So this function is given:

$$f(x)=xe^{-2x}$$

I have to calculate its Taylor series around $x=1$ and use it in some way to 
calculate the following sum:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n+2}{(2n)!!}$$

I do know the fact: $$(2n)!!=2^nn!$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n+2}{(2n)!!}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n+2}{2^nn!}$$

And after 1st step of taylor series i get this:

$$f(x)=(x-1)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-2(x-1))^n}{n!}= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n2^n(x-1)^{n+1}}{n!} = -1 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}2^n(x-1)^{n+1}}{n!} $$

But I have no idea what to do next.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, It seems easier to separate the sum into the sum of $\frac n{2^nn!}$ and $\frac 2{2^nn!}$.

Comment: That's the Taylor series of $f(x-1)$ isn't it?  Note that $f(1)=e^{-2}$, so the constant term is incorrect.

Comment: How should I fix it?

Comment: Well, you have to actually calculate the Taylor series.  I don't know what it is off the top of my head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

To calculate the Taylor series of $f$, start by calculating the Taylor series of $g(x)=e^{-2x}$.  Obviously, $g^{(n)}(x)=(-2)^ne^{-2x}$ so $g^{(n)}(1)=(-2)^ne^{-2}$ and $$g(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-2)^ne^{-2}(x-1)^n$$ is the Taylor series of $g$ about $x=1$.

Now $f(x)=xg(x)=(1+(x-1))g(x)$, so you can easily get the Taylor series for $f$ about $x=1$.